# Weird texture on surface of model

Tags: texturing, shaders

I am currently making my own Overwatch Wallpaper and are doing the logo of it right now. So I have moddled a it and painted texture on it, as we know the design. But for any reason the texture is looking like this: 
[image: render]

You can see the darker stroke in the bottom of the picture and on the left.
Why did it happen and how can I get rid of this? More pictures of the model following.

Untextured: 
[image: untextured]

the mesh:

[image: mesh1]

[image: mesh2]

in paint mode:

[image: paint mode]

and then the texture as a image itself.

[image: texture(defuse)]

Comment: I don't see any issues, could you post a better image? Do you really need an image based texture here at all? Sound's like overkill if your object gonna be simply flat colored. You could just assign two differently coloured materials.

Comment: well I am not very experienced with blender and this was a way I found at the intenet. What I think looks weird is that where the spikes go inside there is a bit a different shading on the ring. It is a bit darker. But I will trie it.

Comment: well, thank you, that solved the problem, but why did it look the way it did when I used the image?

Comment: Add Texture Coordinate with your node setup & connect Texture Coordinate (UV) to Image Texture. This can solve the problem!

Comment: @Sheroz Khan unfortunately this did not work. I connected UV with vector at the textures, but it did not change it.

Comment: Connecting UV output socket from Texture Coordinate node can't change anything in material here by definition as texture will use selected UV map anyway. I don't have idea why assigning materials instead of texture solved it, if your problem is around selected edge loop on screenshots then there is much more dense geometry smoothened with Subsurf which can lead to shading artifacts. If it isn't visible now then it's fine.

Comment: How does it look if you simply use a generated image with the color map or the uv squares? I wonder if when you use a generic white texture if it will still show that way. The fact that the error is across the mirror just means it is in the are in the image.

Answer (score 1):

I have found a solution to this. So I had to use two different materials for both the yellow top and the silver part of the logo. I heared that this issue is caused by too dense geometry there.